# Listing all my files modified more than X days ago, in long format

Tags: shell, wildcards

How can I list in long format all files (located in a directory) which belong to me (rights) and were modified more than 7 days ago?

Answer (score 2):

Use the find command with an argument for files owned by a given username and modified over a certain time.

```
find -user username -mtime +7
```

**EDIT**: Optionally (if you use GNU find, mandatory if you use other implementations) you can add a directory location to search in like this: `find /path/to/search -user username -mtime +7`. GNU find assumes you want to search from the current directory if you do not specify a path.

Comment: you're missing the directory name in that find command

Comment: @Mat: depends if it is the GNU or BSD version of `find`. Here it looks like the GNU one.

Answer (score 1):

In zsh:

```
ls -ld *(u$UIDm+7)
```

`u` and `m` are [globbing qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#SEC87) to match files by owner and modification time respectively.